# Does Docker Alpine images include npm?

Tags: docker, npm, alpine-linux

I'm setting docker container to bundle my frontend assets with npm and Webpack. I would like to use lightweight Docker image for the purpose. Does the images from https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine come with npm?

inside my docker-compose.yml file I have

```
services:
    assets:
        image: alpine:3.9.2
        working_dir: /home/node/app/assets
        volumes:
        - ./src/app/assets:/home/alpine/app/assets/

    command: "npm run bundle"
```

Expect `npm run bundle` to run successfully

I got 
ERROR: for assets  Cannot start service assets: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"npm\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Comment: You can just `docker run --rm alpine npm` to try it.  (But, being a bare-minimum image, no, it won’t.)

Comment: No, it doesn't come with npm. You'd want to use one of the node images such as https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/de76fb48b532d6be012098dc3538bd15329a27d0/8/alpine/Dockerfile which has an alpine base image but comes with npm.

Comment: Alpine = one of the numerous Linux distribution like Ubuntu or Debian. If you translate that to Windows world your question is like asking if Windows 7 comes bundled with a C# IDE. The answer is obviously no and that is the philosophy of docker, having small, one task images. As pointed by @mtt_g, though, most images have an alpine version. More info on alpine: https://alpinelinux.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In docker, Alpine linux is designed as a mininmal base image to keep image size small and also reduce it's attack surface. Additional software like `nodejs` (which contains `npm`) needs manual installation [using corresponding apk packages](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=npm&branch=edge) like `apk add nodejs`. Maybe it's required to update the packages first using `apk update`.

### The docker way

You easily could write a `Dockerfile` and add this as `RUN` statements. But the prefered way is to search in the [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/) for already existing images that fit your needs. In case of npm you'll find a [official nodejs image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node?tab=description) where you simply use the tag of your targeting nodejs version like `10-*` for the latest lts.

Here you've the choice on different base-images. For lts as an example, you could use `10-jessie` or what you want: `10-alpine`. This has only 24mb where the `10-stretch` would require 346mb of storage.

To use it, change `image: alpine:3.9.2` to `image: node: 10-alpine` in your `docker-compose.yml` file.